# Set custom "id" field in EF core 3.1 cosmos

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, ef-core-3.1

Currently with a sample model like

```
public class Order
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int? TrackingNumber { get; set; }
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}
```

would generate document in Cosmos as

```
{
    "Id": "7eb3a83a-f4ed-4670-9c82-ff21e97b89de",
    "PartitionKey": "12345",
    "TrackingNumber": null,
    "id": "Order|7eb3a83a-f4ed-4670-9c82-ff21e97b89de" //NOTICE!

}
```

'id' property is being automatically set by Ef as "Order|7eb3a83a-f4ed-4670-9c82-ff21e97b89de".

So, basically the format for 'id' is

`{ClassName(discriminator)}|{Id}`

Question is how could I explicitly set "id" property?

I would like to instead set 'id' as

`{ClassName(discriminator)}|{PartitionKey}`

or just the

`{PartitionKey}`

I also do not want to use 'id' backing field.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, when you say you don't want to use the `id` backing field. Comsos DB documents *must* have an `id` property - you can't avoid that (and it's the only property usable with direct reads). You're free to use other properties as well, but no, you cannot avoid `id`.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the field part of your primary key (using `HasKey` method or `[Key]` attribute), CosmosDB won't use the value generator for it. You can then use your custom format for the `id` field.

At least that is what I am getting from this: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17751